# WPF: Change text and image colour on button's mouseover state

Tags: wpf, vb.net

So I have a WPF button that has an image (icon) and a TextBlock underneath that. When the user hovers over the button,I want the icon and text to change colour,however as simple as that seems I always get stuck one step before figuring it all out!

Here's example XAML of the button and the relevant part of my custom template...

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="87" Margin="141,455,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Style="{DynamicResource MenuButton}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Cursor="Hand">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="Resources/my_icon_normalState.png" Width="25" Height="25"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" TextAlignment="Center">
            Button<LineBreak></LineBreak> Text
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="15">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#209452"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFECECEC"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I understand I have to place something on the "IsMouseOver" trigger,but I cannot seem to figure out exactly what... A few examples have led me to think of having to change the "Content" property,but it will not allow me to change both the image and text at the same time.

Comment: You should consider to use paths instead of bitmaps to get your icons nice and sorted

Comment: How are you going to change the colour of your image at all?  You would need a path or shape of some sort rather than an image.

Comment: I would replace the image source,I have two images; one grey and one white. I do not know how to work with paths!

Comment: you can use the free tool inkscapt to export dxf/vector files as XAML
but generally you get better code by doing it yourself

Comment: Can I do that from Adobe XD?

Comment: You do that from inkscape but you can use any bitmap file. I trace bitmaps in inkscape. Save as xaml. Extract the data from there to use as a geometry. Or use standard icons from syncfusion metro studio

Comment: Well I can try going XD --> Export as SVG --> Inkscape --> Export as XAML then. That sounds like it would work. It does not solve the initial problem but it does solve a couple of very minor antialiasing issues I've had here and there.

Comment: Yes, if you can save as svg then you don't need to do any tracing and you'll get better results. I think svg internally uses the same stuff for it's paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you wont be able to change an actual image content of your button easily. Thats why there are paths. Paths are structures similar to a vector/SVG sketch and can be created using tools like inkscape.

In the example below there is a trigger included thats used to change the fill of a path object.

```
            <Button>
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Brown"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Busy</TextBlock>
                    <Viewbox Height="25" Width="25">
                        <Path Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Data="M 27 0 C 23.699219 0 21 2.699219 21 6 C 21 9.300781 23.699219 12 27 12 C 30.300781 12 33 9.300781 33 6 C 33 2.699219 30.300781 0 27 0 Z M 27 2 C 29.222656 2 31 3.777344 31 6 C 31 8.222656 29.222656 10 27 10 C 24.777344 10 23 8.222656 23 6 C 23 3.777344 24.777344 2 27 2 Z M 21.90625 12.90625 C 20.007813 12.90625 18.339844 14.074219 17.59375 15.8125 C 17.582031 15.832031 17.570313 15.855469 17.5625 15.875 L 12.5 29.90625 L 12.46875 29.90625 C 12.460938 29.925781 12.476563 29.949219 12.46875 29.96875 C 10.75 34.09375 13.671875 39 18.1875 39 C 21.191406 39 24.601563 38.355469 26.21875 38.03125 L 25.21875 45.46875 C 24.953125 47.597656 26.421875 49.734375 28.6875 50 C 28.730469 50.003906 28.769531 50.003906 28.8125 50 L 29.1875 50 C 31.175781 50 32.921875 48.53125 33.1875 46.53125 L 35 33.53125 C 35 33.519531 35 33.511719 35 33.5 C 35.128906 32.324219 34.742188 31.085938 33.84375 30.15625 L 36.65625 29.90625 C 36.667969 29.90625 36.675781 29.90625 36.6875 29.90625 C 38.582031 29.753906 40.007813 28.066406 39.90625 26.1875 C 39.90625 26.175781 39.90625 26.167969 39.90625 26.15625 C 39.90625 26.144531 39.90625 26.136719 39.90625 26.125 C 39.867188 24.191406 38.058594 22.859375 36.21875 23 L 31.03125 23.4375 L 29.5625 18.03125 C 29.164063 16.683594 28.859375 15.503906 28.1875 14.53125 C 27.515625 13.558594 26.34375 12.90625 24.90625 12.90625 Z M 21.90625 14.90625 L 24.90625 14.90625 C 25.871094 14.90625 26.152344 15.105469 26.53125 15.65625 C 26.90625 16.199219 27.230469 17.238281 27.625 18.5625 L 29.34375 24.75 C 29.460938 25.214844 29.894531 25.53125 30.375 25.5 L 36.375 25 C 37.117188 24.941406 37.90625 25.554688 37.90625 26.1875 C 37.90625 26.21875 37.90625 26.25 37.90625 26.28125 C 37.96875 27.167969 37.398438 27.84375 36.53125 27.90625 C 36.519531 27.90625 36.511719 27.90625 36.5 27.90625 L 28.59375 28.59375 L 28.40625 28.59375 C 27.730469 28.59375 27.148438 28.191406 26.96875 27.53125 L 26.5625 26.125 C 26.445313 25.703125 26.066406 25.410156 25.632813 25.394531 C 25.195313 25.382813 24.800781 25.652344 24.65625 26.0625 L 22.96875 30.65625 C 22.839844 30.988281 22.902344 31.367188 23.128906 31.644531 C 23.351563 31.921875 23.710938 32.058594 24.0625 32 L 30.65625 31 C 30.667969 30.988281 30.675781 30.980469 30.6875 30.96875 C 31.386719 30.828125 31.910156 31.003906 32.40625 31.5 C 32.863281 31.957031 33.058594 32.65625 33 33.25 C 33 33.257813 33 33.273438 33 33.28125 L 31.21875 46.25 C 31.21875 46.261719 31.21875 46.269531 31.21875 46.28125 C 31.085938 47.28125 30.199219 48 29.1875 48 L 28.90625 48 C 27.78125 47.867188 27.070313 46.808594 27.1875 45.75 L 27.1875 45.71875 L 28.40625 36.9375 C 28.457031 36.609375 28.339844 36.277344 28.097656 36.050781 C 27.851563 35.824219 27.511719 35.734375 27.1875 35.8125 C 27.1875 35.8125 21.566406 37 18.1875 37 C 15.125 37 13.085938 33.550781 14.3125 30.6875 C 14.324219 30.667969 14.335938 30.644531 14.34375 30.625 L 19.40625 16.59375 C 19.414063 16.578125 19.429688 16.578125 19.4375 16.5625 L 19.4375 16.53125 C 19.902344 15.511719 20.828125 14.90625 21.90625 14.90625 Z M 25.6875 29.03125 C 25.832031 29.234375 25.941406 29.460938 26.125 29.625 L 25.4375 29.75 Z M 16.09375 40.6875 C 16.03125 40.703125 15.964844 40.722656 15.90625 40.75 C 15.042969 41.027344 14.371094 41.511719 13.96875 42.0625 C 13.566406 42.613281 13.410156 43.175781 13.3125 43.625 C 13.226563 44.027344 13.191406 44.296875 13.15625 44.40625 C 13.125 44.414063 13.09375 44.425781 13.0625 44.4375 C 13.050781 44.4375 13.042969 44.4375 13.03125 44.4375 C 12.835938 44.488281 12.664063 44.597656 12.53125 44.75 C 11.257813 45.308594 10.449219 46.289063 10.1875 47.1875 C 9.882813 48.226563 10 49.125 10 49.125 C 10.0625 49.628906 10.492188 50.003906 11 50 L 20.5 50 C 20.804688 50 21.089844 49.863281 21.28125 49.625 C 22.226563 48.410156 22.207031 46.847656 21.59375 45.6875 C 20.992188 44.546875 19.855469 43.6875 18.46875 43.53125 L 18.46875 43.5 C 18.089844 43.4375 18.007813 43.378906 17.8125 43.09375 C 17.617188 42.808594 17.398438 42.234375 17.15625 41.40625 C 17.03125 40.976563 16.636719 40.683594 16.1875 40.6875 C 16.15625 40.6875 16.125 40.6875 16.09375 40.6875 Z M 15.71875 43.125 C 15.859375 43.484375 15.945313 43.910156 16.15625 44.21875 C 16.585938 44.855469 17.304688 45.363281 18.125 45.5 C 18.15625 45.5 18.1875 45.5 18.21875 45.5 C 18.898438 45.566406 19.53125 46.035156 19.84375 46.625 C 20.085938 47.085938 20.078125 47.539063 19.875 48 L 12.0625 48 C 12.082031 47.878906 12.054688 47.878906 12.09375 47.75 C 12.230469 47.28125 12.539063 46.882813 13.125 46.59375 C 13.574219 46.941406 14.039063 47.167969 14.46875 47.28125 C 15.148438 47.460938 15.75 47.5 15.75 47.5 C 16.300781 47.527344 16.769531 47.097656 16.796875 46.546875 C 16.824219 45.996094 16.394531 45.527344 15.84375 45.5 C 15.84375 45.5 15.445313 45.460938 15 45.34375 C 14.964844 45.335938 14.96875 45.324219 14.9375 45.3125 C 15.164063 44.816406 15.203125 44.414063 15.28125 44.0625 C 15.359375 43.710938 15.441406 43.429688 15.59375 43.21875 C 15.617188 43.1875 15.691406 43.15625 15.71875 43.125 Z "/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

You can use it like this but it would really make more sense to create a custom control based on a button that will allow you to set a "PathData" property or something and display it accordingly.

Comment: I'll try this... but would I have to define a different template for every icon I want to use,then? Or can the "Path" be somehow databound?

Comment: no of cause you can bind it as well and put the path insided the button this was just a quick example. I generally would recommend using a custom control for that but i will give you a style to achive something similar in a minute

Comment: I would use a custom control but the project I'm working on has specific time constraints so I try to work within those!

Comment: Adapted my code accordingly,but it does not seem to work; nothing changes. The background changes,but the foreground stays gray (in this case).

Comment: did you copy paste this code and it did not change color?
I added a control template to overwrite the orginal one so the background doesnt change anymore

Comment: Well I copy/pasted the relevant parts. When I copy/pasted this as-is it was as though I had not reset the template at all,like nothing was working. Seems like the IsMouseOver trigger on your example isn't applied at all!

Comment: I've edited my comment accordingly. Appears that,frustratingly,nothing changes on MouseOver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189461/discussion-between-denis-schaf-and-f-bill).

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to change the color of the icon "Resources/my_icon_normalState.png" but you could change the loaded icon to to a different icon when it IsMousedOver. This would look something like

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

But instead of changing to background (unless that's what you want to do) you would load a new image.